# RavenDB : XmlNodeConverter only supports deserializing XmlDocuments

Tags: xml, json, serialization, ravendb

I can't deserialize "XmlElement" objects from RavenDb. I obtain the error : "XmlNodeConverter only supports deserializing XmlDocuments".

The code for the class FooEventType has been generated by Svcutil tool (from wsdl and xsd files).

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "urn:eglobal:eis:xsd:1")]
public partial class FooEventType 
{
    private Foo[] fooListField;

    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("foo", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public Foo[] fooList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fooListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fooListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Into this class, there are an "Any" property of type "XmlElement" which causes an issue during Json deserialization with RavenDb. There are no problem during the serialization.

The JSON object serialized in my database :

```
{
  "fooList": [
    {
      "Value": "test1"
    },
    {
      "Value": "test2"
    }
  ],
  "Any": [
    {
      "testOfProp": {
        "#whitespace": [
          "\n",
          "\n"
        ],
        "testOfValue": "XYZ"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The exception detail when deserializing during my query in database :

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Could not convert document FooEventTypes/8961 to entity of type EWcfService.FooEventType
  Source=Raven.Client.Lightweight
  StackTrace:
       at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity(Type entityType, String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata)
       at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity(Type entityType, String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, Boolean noTracking)
       at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T](String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, Boolean noTracking)
       at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject result)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete[T]()
       at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GetEnumerator()
       at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Epcis11WcfService.RavenDb.RavenDbEpcis.poll(pollRequest request) in d:\Activite\PROJ\DEV\Main\ESolution2\ESolution2\E11WcfService\RavenDb\RavenDbE.cs:line 99
       at E11WcfService.Query.poll(pollRequest request) in d:\Activite\PROJ\DEV\Main\ESolution2\ESolution2\E11WcfService\Query.svc.cs:line 47
       at SyncInvokepoll(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
  InnerException: Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Could not read value for property: Any
       Source=Raven.Abstractions
       StackTrace:
            at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
            at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
            at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
            at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
            at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
            at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
            at Raven.Client.Connection.DocumentConventionJsonExtensions.Deserialize(RavenJObject self, Type type, DocumentConvention convention)
            at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity(Type entityType, String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata)
       InnerException: Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
            HResult=-2146233088
            Message=XmlNodeConverter only supports deserializing XmlDocuments
            Source=Raven.Abstractions
            StackTrace:
                 at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
                 at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
                 at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
                 at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
                 at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
                 at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
                 at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. I convert XmlElement[] to XmlDocument[] when serializing thanks to a getter/setter and i use the [XmlIgnore] and [JsonIgnore] attributes.
But if you have another solution, I am still interested.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "urn:eglobal:eis:xsd:1")]
public partial class FooEventType 
{
    private Foo[] fooListField;

    private System.Xml.XmlDocument[] anyField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("foo", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public Foo[] fooList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fooListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fooListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public XmlElement[] Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField.Select(x => x.DocumentElement).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.anyField = new XmlDocument[value.Count()];
                for (int i = 0; i < value.Count(); i++)
                {
                    this.anyField[i] = new XmlDocument();
                    this.anyField[i].LoadXml(value[i].OuterXml);
                }
            }


        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Any")]
    public System.Xml.XmlDocument[] Any_ForRavenJsonSerialization
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }

        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

}
```